# How do I make Scrapy print all duplicate urls?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am getting this message once in the logs:

```
2014-01-16 12:41:45+0100 [mybot] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://mydomain/someurl> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)
```

The url was requested using Request() and it says it's a duplicate on the very first time it requests it. I don't know what's causing this. What can I do to debug this? How do I make it print all the duplicate urls that it's filtering?

Comment: Is the page being redirected to the same page or someting?

Comment: No, it is not a redirect. I created the Request() but it does not even send the request but instead skips it saying it's a duplicate.

Comment: I had that once, and in this case you can add `dont_filter=True` when creating your `Request`

Comment: Adding dont_filter=True will cause more problems that it tries to solve. I do want to filter duplicates but only if it's REALLY a duplicate.

Comment: Well, Scrapy doesnt filter without reason, so hopefully you'll find some explanation with the console log (that you could share here, removing domain info if needed) and maybe with the DupeFilter I suggest below. Is there a meta refresh in the page maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create your own DupeFilter

```
from scrapy.dupefilter import RFPDupeFilter

class VerboseRFPDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def log(self, request, spider):
        fmt = "Filtered duplicate request: %(request)s"
        log.msg(format=fmt, request=request, level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
```

and set `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` setting to this new Class (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class)

Answer (score 0):

Try exact url with `curl -v URL` and see if the headers contains a 301 or 302. Alternatively you can try `scrapy shell URL`.

I've seen some sites that redirects to the same page when the parameters are not in the same order or the expected letter case. Scrapy doesn't consider the order or the letter case of the parameters when comparing two request objects.

Comment: I checked that already. It is not a redirect. The URL in question was not requested at all by scrapy. I checked it in wireshark. The request was created myself using Request(). It was never crawled before. Very strange. There is nothing in the console log to post here. It just says duplicate URL but I can clearly see in the console log that it isn't a duplicate and there were never any redirects.

Comment: Are you using `JOBDIR`? In that case the dupefilter persist the requests seen in a file `requests.seen` inside the `JOBDIR`.

Comment: Yes, I am using JOBDIR and I tried deleting it before running it. I tried without a JOBDIR as well.